# How to validate the credentials entered by users with the one in SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, authentication

I'm now working on `Sample login application` in which `user` can `login` with their `username` and `password` by pressing `login button`. If the `user` is new then he/she can also register by choosing `username` and `password`. And this `registration` part of application worked.

---

My actual question is: How do I compare the user entered `credentials` with the one that stored in `database`.

I used `SELECT` query to select the username and pwd as this

```
public void ValidateLogin(String un, String pwd)
     {
        SELECT_FROM = "SELECT u_name, u_pwd FROM" + table_name + "WHERE u_name == " + un + "AND u_pwd ==" + pwd;
        db.execSQL(SELECT_FROM);
     }
```

where `username(un)` and `password(pwd)` comes from another `java file login.java`.

---

**Now please tell me how would I make a successful transition to viewprofile page after successful login?**

Comment: I see four problems right off: 1) SQL isn't java == is invalid syntax for SQL.  Instead use just 1 =.  in SQL it works as assignments and validations.  2) un & pwd are string characters and must be contained in tics (') so... "WHERE u_name = '"& un + "' AND u_pwd= '"+ pwd + "'"  3) This technique is flawed as it leaves yourself open to SQL injection.  Instead use parameters.   4) lastly you need to check the returning row count.  If the rowcount == 1 then return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: Moreover, although android stores database in the application's directory I will not recommend to store passwords as a clear text. I propose to use instead a hash function of password.

Comment: thanks for your answer xQbert and yury...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use `cursor` with `rawquery` to validate username and password in one boolean type of method

    public boolean ValidateLogin(String un, String pwd)
      {
        boolean chklogin=false;      
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT u_name, u_pwd FROM " + table_name + " WHERE u_name = '"+ un + "' AND u_pwd ='"+ pwd + "'", null);

         if(c==null)
        {
            //set boolean var to false
               chklogin=false; 
           //message no such records 
         }

        else
         {
           //set boolean var to true 
               chklogin=true;
               c.moveToFirst(); 
         }

         return chklogin; //boolean var
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use cursor, instead of row queries,

```
String[] selectionArgs = {un,pwd};
Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name, {"u_name", "u_pwd"} , "u_name=? and u_pwd=?", selectionArgs , null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToNext()){
    //Success
}else{
    //Failure
}
cursor.close();
```